# Django CSRF token: Set and Validate of Different Servers?

Tags: django, django-csrf

Say that I have multiple Django servers running on a distributed system. Is it possible to assign the CSRF token on one server and then validate it on another? Would having the same `SECRET_KEY` on all servers be sufficient? Do I need another CSRF-token system altogether?

Comment: are they both using the same database ?

Comment: + are they working in the same domain ??